# How to drag images from a listview (together with an imageview) to pictureboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I am pretty new to C# and struggle a lot with a small project I want to do.

I am busy with something like a collage maker where I have a list of pictures on the left hand side and I want to drag and drop multiple images to the right hand side where I want to be able to move them around to create my collage.

I wanted to show an image but I am not allowed to post images with less than 10 reputation points. But look here for the [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-t1PtUkARFPMzJZSXFQTDNzbGc/view?usp=sharing):

[image]

I can't manage to get it to work. I've looked online for help but I can't really find what I'm looking for. The stuff I do find are too unclear and I struggle to understand.

This is what I have so far for the code to drag and drop from the left to the right but it doesn't work;

```
private void pictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        int len = e.Data.GetFormats().Length - 1;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetFormats()[i].Equals("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection"))
            {
                //The data from the drag source is moved to the target.
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Return if the items are not selected in the ListView control.
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        ListViewItem dragitem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        pictureBox2.Image = imageList1.Images[dragitem.ImageIndex];
        listView1.Items.Remove(dragitem);
    }

    private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

And after I can add image to the left, how can I drag and move them around using the mouse coordinates?

Any help will be appreciated please. 
Everything is done using C# in Windows Forms.

Comment: if you want to place the images into specific slots to form the collage, then I can help you. I mean, you could split the right picturebox into 9 (or whatever) pictureboxes. Then you could code to make the images drop in on the slots and thus form the image. On the other hand, if you want overlapping images which can be placed anywhere inside the picturebox, it would be a lot tougher.

Comment: @FarhanAnam OK, I think that will be a good way to start with.

Comment: Farhan has nailed the first and most important question: Do you want the images to __overlap__ (like a collage) or not (like an image gallery) ??? You __need__ to decide on this and only then we can give advice on how to proceed best. A secondary question would be whether the target shall be editable/moveable once placed?

Comment: Well, the images have to be against each other without any gaps between them. The purpose is mainly for aerial photos that should be stitched together so that it looks like a map. That means they have to be organized in the correct order as well. By making it possible for the images to overlap it will improve the precision of the image afterwards, because the user can then manually fine tune everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example you may want to play with:

It uses a form with a `ListView`, an `ImageList` and a `Panel` to hold the `PictureBoxes`.

You could use a `FlowLayoutPanel` but this won't let you move the `Pictureboxes` later.

You also could use a grid of `Panels` and their `BackgroundImage`.

First we set up the form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KeyPreview = true;
    FillLV(10);
    AddPBs(36);
    listView1.MouseMove += listView1_MouseMove;
}

void FillLV(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) listView1.Items.Add("Item" + i, i);
}

void AddPBs(int count)
{
    int iWidth = imageList1.ImageSize.Width;
    int iHeight = imageList1.ImageSize.Height;
    int cols = panel1.ClientSize.Width / iWidth;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
        PB.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        PB.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        PB.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(iWidth , iHeight );
        PB.Location = new Point(iWidth * (i % cols), iHeight * (i / cols));
        PB.Parent = panel1;
        PB.DragEnter += PB_DragEnter;
        PB.DragDrop += PB_DragDrop;
        PB.AllowDrop = true;
        PB.MouseClick += (ss, ee) => { currentPB = PB; PB.Focus(); };
    }
}
```

Note how we add events to the dynamically created `PictureBoxes` and how we set their hidden `AllowDrop` property.

Also note the little lambda to make the `MouseClick` prepare for moving them around with the keyboard.

For this we will also need a reference to the current box:

```
PictureBox currentPB = null;
```

Now we start the dragging. This should **not** be done in the `MouseDown` or else it will interfere with normal selection and also happen before the new selection is made..

**Either** you do it in the `MouseMove`:

```
void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems[0], DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

**Or** (**Update**) for `ListViews` better and much simpler (thanks Hans!) in their `ItemDrag` event:

```
private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

**Update**: Both ways now use the dragged Item, not just its imageIndex, to make it simpler to remove the Item from the LV..

```
void PB_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem))) 
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

void PB_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
    var item = (ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem));
    int index = item.ImageIndex;
    pb.Image = imageList1.Images[index];  // make sure you have images for indices!!

}
```

Finally we use the keyboard to move the current box around. I have added code to bring it up and down in the z-order as well.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentPB == null) return;
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left) currentPB.Left -= 1;
    else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right) currentPB.Left += 1;
    else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up) currentPB.Top -= 1;
    else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down) currentPB.Top += 1;
    else
    { 
        int z = panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(currentPB);
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Home) panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(currentPB, 0);
        else if (e.KeyData == Keys.End) 
             panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(currentPB, panel1.Controls.Count);
        else if (e.KeyData == Keys.PageUp) 
             panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(currentPB, z + 1);
        else if (e.KeyData == Keys.PageDown) 
             { if (z > 0) panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(currentPB, z - 1); }
    }
    panel1.Invalidate();

}
```

For this to work the form must have : `KeyPreview = true;`

Note that the sizes in an `ImageList` are restricted to 256x256. So you may want to use only the index and use it to load larger images from disk..

Comment: First of; thank you very much for your time and effort to help me. I did everything you did and there are now those 10 Items in my `listview`. But when i click on something and then drag it to the `panel` I get an Exception "`An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.`"

Comment: Do I understand you wrong somehow somewhere or did I something silly? I just tried it out first on a new win-forms project and inserted all the code snippets under each other

Comment: Hm, that sounds as if your imagelist is empty? Please note that I am updating the answer, making use of Hans' (now delted) answer to help you remove the dragged items from the listview, which is a little hard using only the imageindex..

Comment: Pfff sorry, my bad, I quickly started a new project to try it out and forgot to add images - so far it works pretty good!

Comment: See the updated answer; using the ListViewItem as the dragged object is simpler and more flexible..

Comment: I almost forgot about the part where I can use the keyboard to move the current box around. I don't understand, how does it work because it doesn't seem to work if i click on a `picturebox` (inside the panel) and use the arrow keys to move it. I'm just curios but otherwise it isn't that important.

Comment: Well, it does work here. You need to set the Form's `KeyPreview = true` If this doesn't help set a breakpoint on the Form1_KeyDown event to see if it gets hit. Then we'll see further..

Comment: My KeyPreview is set to true. If I look through the code, I can't see that the Form1_KeyDown event (method) is actually used somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean? It is an event. Did you hook it up??

Comment: It is in my program, but shouldn't I call that event from somewhere else?

Comment: Um, it is an event that (as the name implies) gets triggered when you press a key on the keyboard. (If it is hooked up)

Comment: I can't get to that part with a breakpoint, `listView1_ItemDrag` constantly want me to drag something then it goes back and loop in the same `listView1_ItemDrag` to drag something.

Comment: I really can't follow you. After you have dragged an image or many of them  you click one, then you can move it with the arrow keys.

Comment: OK, then I don't know because it doesn't work, if I click on an image after I dragged it and try to move it nothing happens...

Comment: Once more: Is the `Form1_KeyDown` event code hooked up??? If it is and the form has `KeyPreview=true` then you should enter the event code at the end of my answer. (If you are not sure what 'hooked up' means, please ask!)

Comment: Ah. It is the most basic thing you need to learn to code in VS. In short it means that the event name, here `Form1_KeyDown` is connected to the event. To do so one can either use code, like I did for the events of the dynamically created PBs or one inserts it into the correct slot of the events pane of the property tab. Select the Form, open the events pane (the one with the yellow flash) and locate the `KeyDown` event! Here insert the name of the event and you are done.

Comment: The result is reflected in the form_designer.cs file and it is the same thing (in reverse)  as double clicking that spot and then filling in the generated code stub.. Controls have many events; one is the default event and this can be generated by double clicking the control insetlf in the designer. But you will need all 3 ways to gernarte and hook up the events..

Comment: I feel like a reel idiot now. I'm so sorry for your wasted time but I also have to thank you for it. I appreciate the effort you did to help me very much, it works absolutely perfect now.