# How can I generate dinamically a button grid in a winform application which fits to the window size

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried many versions, but most of the tutorials are made for wpf apps. 
Anyway, I can make some kind of grid, but some buttons are out of the form, and the spaceng among them is too large (And of course, if I resize the form, the grid still in the same size).

Here's on of my tries, which isn't works correctly:

```
int size = 32;
_buttonGrid = new Button[size, size];
for (Int32 i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (Int32 j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        _buttonGrid[i, j] = new Button();
        _buttonGrid[i, j].Location = new Point( size * j,  size * i); 
        _buttonGrid[i, j].Size = new Size(flowLayoutPanel1.Width / size, flowLayoutPanel1.Height / size); 
        _buttonGrid[i, j].Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 6, FontStyle.Bold); 
        _buttonGrid[i, j].Enabled = true; 
        _buttonGrid[i, j].TabIndex = 10 + i * size + j; 
        _buttonGrid[i, j].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; stípus

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(_buttonGrid[i, j]);
    }
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920767/c-sharp-how-to-drag-images-from-a-listview-together-with-an-imageview-to-pic/32922380#32920767) answer for a piece of code that fills a panel with a grid of pictureboxes. You should be able to adapt it easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx) with columns and rows and put your buttons in it.

For example, add a TableLayoutPanel to your form and put this code in Load event of form:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rowCount = 10;
    var columnCount = 10;

    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = columnCount;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = rowCount;

    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100 / columnCount ));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100 / rowCount ));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {

            var button = new Button();
            button.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", i, j);
            button.Name = string.Format("button_{0}{1}", i, j);
            button.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button, j, i);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: but just one more thing... If I set for example 20 to row and col, the buttons in the last row and the last col are bigger than others. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @NvrJr Set the `Dock` property of `TableLayoutPanel` to `DockStyle.Fill` then pay attention to first and second `For` loop, that I set the column style and row style to be based on percent.

Comment: Neat and straightforward solution (y)